# Proof of number of flops required to reduce a n×(n+1) matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

While studying the row reduction algorithm to solve a linear system, I came across a statement saying that "a flop is one arithmetic operation on two real floating point numbers. For an $n×(n+1)$ matrix, the reduction to echelon form can take $\frac {2n^3}{3}+\frac {n^2}{2}-\frac {7n}{6}.$ In contrast, further reduction to reduced echelon form needs at most $n^2$."

Does anyone know how to prove the above 2 formulas? Please bear in mind that I have only just begun to study linear algebra, and thus am unfamiliar with many technical vocabularies in linear algebra.<\p>

Answer (score 1):

The way to prove them
is to look at the algorithm
that does the computation.

If a operation count is
of order $n^d$,
then, typically,
the algorithm has
$d$ nested loops.

So look and count.

Answer (score 1):

In the standard row echelon form algorithm (without pivoting), at stage number $k$ you already have $0$'s below the diagonal in the first $k-1$ columns of your matrix $A$.  You divide each of the $n+1-k$ elements in row $k$ to the right of the diagonal by $A_{k,k}$: that's $n+1-k$ operations.  Then for each of the 
$(n-k)(n+1-k)$ elements $A_{ij}$ with $i > k$ and $j > k$, you replace $A_{ij}$ by 
$A_{ij} - A_{ik} A_{kj}$: that's one multiplication and one subtraction for each, thus $2 (n-k)(n+1-k)$ operations.  Then you replace $A_{kk}$ by $1$ and $A_{ik}$ by $0$ for $i > k$: no arithmetic involved there.  The total is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \left( n+1-k + 2 (n-k)(n+1-k)\right)$$
which turns out to be $$\dfrac{2}{3} n^3 + \frac{n^2}{2} - \dfrac{n}{6}$$ 
This is $n$ more than the answer you were given.  I don't see where they are saving those $n$ operations.

Comment: I think the answer is that one cannot save those operations. A simple test: for $n=1$ your formula gives $1$ operation which is correct while the formula provided gives $0$.

Comment: Why do you divide $n+1-k$ elements to the right of the diagonal? What part does this correspond to in doing echelon form by hand.